# customer debt report laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel

I have laravel project with vouchers table 
this is the structure of the vouchers table

```
      Schema::create('vouchers', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('voucher_number',25)->unique();
        $table->integer('voucher_dealer');
        $table->date('voucher_date');
        $table->integer('voucher_customer_id');
        $table->double('voucher_amount');
        $table->text('voucher_note');
        $table->integer('voucher_type');
        $table->integer('voucher_inserter');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();   
    });
```

And the model name is Voucher

Now when i need to get customer voucher i use this relation

```
public function CustomerReportGet(Request $request) 
{
    $full = Voucher::where('voucher_customer_id','=',$request->customer_id)->sum('voucher_amount');
    if($request->from_date == '' and $request->to_date == '')
        $data = Voucher::where('voucher_customer_id','=',$request->customer_id)->get();
    elseif($request->from_date <> '' or $request->to_date <> '')
    {
        $data = Voucher::where('voucher_customer_id','=',$request->customer_id)->
                whereBetween('created_at',array($request->from_date,$request->to_date));
    }
    return array($full,$data);
}
```

And i have them as ajax request in the blade page 
now my problem is that when i create the report 
its should be like this ..
customer id 
voucher date 
voucher amount
customer balance till the voucher date
how can i let laravel always sum the voucher_amount till every voucher_date in the blade 
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
public function CustomerReportGet(Request $request) 
{
    $full = Voucher::where('voucher_customer_id','=',$request->customer_id);
    if($request->from_date == '' and $request->to_date == '')
        $full->sum('voucher_amount')->get();
    elseif($request->from_date <> '' or $request->to_date <> '')
    {
                $full->whereBetween('created_at',array($request->from_date,$request->to_date))->sum('voucher_amount')->get();
    }


    return array($full,$data);
}
```